# How do I create a custom api endpoint?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress plugin development. I currently am trying to develop an addition calculator plugin which has the API endpoint at example.com/calc/add. How would I add a new URL endpoint to my WordPress installation so the plugin can take in 'POST' requests (numbers in a comma-separated list) and return the data accordingly after adding the numbers? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use parse_request hook for creating end point, below is the example from one of my plugin

```
// this example creates endpoint like http://emerico.in/api/v2

add_action('parse_request', 'endpoint', 0);
add_action('init', 'add_endpoint');

/**
 * @param null
 * @return null
 * @description Create a independent endpoint
 */
function endpoint()
{
    global $wp;

    $endpoint_vars = $wp->query_vars;

    // if endpoint
    if ($wp->request == 'api/v2') {

        // Your own function to process end pint
        $this->processEndPoint($_REQUEST);

        // After all redirect to home page
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    } elseif (isset($endpoint_vars['tracking']) && !empty($endpoint_vars['tracking'])) {
        $request = [
            'tracking_id' => $endpoint_vars['tracking']
        ];

        $this->processEndPoint($request);
    } elseif (isset($_GET['utm_source']) && !empty($_GET['utm_source'])){
        $this->processGoogleTracking($_GET);
    }
}

/**
 * @param null
 * @return null
 * @description Create a permalink endpoint for projects tracking
 */
function add_endpoint()
{

    add_rewrite_endpoint('tracking', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES, true);

}
```

Comment: May i as what `add_rewrite_endpoint('tracking', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES, true);` does?

Comment: I am using this for adding tracking var to query .. however you can get more information about it from here https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint

Answer (score 0):

## Minimal code

This creates the `custom-endpoint` like so `http://example.com/custom-endpoint`.

```php
add_action('parse_request', 'register_endpoint', 0);

function register_endpoint() {
    global $wp;

    if ($wp->request == 'custom-endpoint') {
        echo 'hello world'; // process anything here
        exit;
    }
}
```